# Manifoldjs Failed to run the app for Android platform

Tags: android, hosted-app, manifoldjs

I followed the following steps in order to generate a `mobile app` for my website using `manifoldjs`:

```
1. > npm install manifoldjs –g
2. > manifoldjs http://www.mywebsite.com
3. > cd /generated/folder
4. > manifoldjs run Android
```

Everything worked perfectly except for the last command `manifoldjs run Android` it throws the following error: `Failed to run the app for Android platform` am I missing something in my installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(assuming you are using windows 10)

I had this initially make sure you have java development environment installed.
Make sure android SDK is also installed and you have the android environment variable pointing to the sdk: 'ANDROID_HOME'

hope that helps.

Manoj